# Spark Streaming -- (Top K requests) how to maintain a state on a driver?

Tags: streaming, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a stream of logs with URLs users request.
**Every minute** I want to get top100 pages requested **during all the time** and save it to HDFS.

I understand how to maintain a number of requests for each url:

```
 val ratingItemsStream : DStream[(String,Long)] = lines
      .map(LogEntry(_))
      .map(entry => (entry.url, 1L))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
      .updateStateByKey(updateRequestCount)
// this provides a DStream of Tuple of [Url, # of requests]
```

But what to I do next?
Obviously I need to pass all the updates to host to  maintain a priorityqueue, and then take top K of it every 1 minute.

How can I achieve this?

**UPD:** I've seen spark examples and algebird's MapMonoid used there. But since I do not understand how it works(surpisingly no information was found online), I don't want to use it. There must me some way, right?

Comment: Where do you want to 'pass' this info to?

Comment: @maasg I've updated the question so it might be a bit more clear now.

Comment: Re: Algebird: a priority queue monoid would be a better fit for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach it by taking a x-minute window aggregations of the data and applying  sorting to get the ranking.

```
val window = ratingItemStream.window(Seconds(windowSize), Seconds(windowSize))
window.forEachRDD{rdd =>
    val byScore = rdd.map(_.swap).sortByKey(ascending=false).zipWithIndex
    val top100 = byScore.collect{case ((score, url), index) if (index<100) => (url, score)}
    top100.saveAsTextFile("./path/to/file/")
}
```

(sample code, not tested!)

Note that `rdd.top(x)` will give you better performance than sorting/zipping but it returns an array, and therefore, you're on your own to save it to hdfs using the hadoop API (which is an option, I think)

Comment: but what is the use of .window() here? what sense does it make if duration == slide ?